# PDO Statements And XSS Attack

Tags: php, pdo, xss

I've one POST parameter in one of the page hosted at localhost server.

```
$name = addslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
```

and using PDO prepared statements in one of the Update.php page and,

When i try to submit the field with the following data, it shows a ALERT Popup which leads to XSS attack, so how can i prevent this attack so that SQL Injection and XSS won't works.

```
abc"><script>alert(1);</script>
```

Here's the SQL Query which i'm using -

```
$query = "UPDATE table set name =? where id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute(array($name,$id));
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you are submitting this `abc"><script>alert(1);</script>` whole string?

Comment: Yes i'm submitting the above string in Input field..

Comment: And you dont need to `addslashes` if you are using bound parameters

Comment: Why are you submitting a piece of javascript

Comment: Then how can i protect simply GET and POST parameters in a form with above PDO Query so that it won't lead to SQL injection and XSS Attacks ?

Comment: I'm just testing myself with the form submission because i'm developing a site with multi role so its a big risk for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code injection is 100% context sensitive. It doesn't happen just because a malicious user types "dangerous" characters.

- To insert stuff into DB, get rid of `addslashes()`. You're already using prepared statements to separate code from data.
- To inject a string literal into HTML code you can use `htmlspecialchars()`.
- To inject a string literal into JavaScript code you can use e.g. `json_encode()`.

… and so on. There're as many injections as languages and each type needs to be addressed independently.